# combining specific row values within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's an image of my dataframe.

[image]

I am working on a dataframe that displays the amount of offices in each state.  I am looking to combine the office count value in the state of CA which is split up into 2 separate rows/indexes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: You can use `df.groupby('state')['office_count'].sum()` to get you the sum by state

Comment: Are the two index numbers `25` and `13` important for you? If yes, what do you want to do about them? If not, the above groupby will address the problem

Comment: these were the original index positions so not entirely relevant.  Thank you this worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby the state column and sum the office_count column.

df = df.groupby('state').agg({'office_count' : 'sum'}).reset_index()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the groupby function for this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'index': [4, 41, 26, 25, 13, 47, 20],
        'state': ['AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT'],
        'office_count': [28, 23, 76, 408, 374, 150, 158]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.groupby(['state']).agg({'office_count': 'sum'})
```